# Is there some direct function in linux to retrieve the entire command line arguments in the application

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments

The command line arguments are received as the parameters in the int main function.

However, In windows there is also an alternative function **GetCommandLineW()** that retrieves the entire command line as a single string, which helps to get the arguments anytime later in the application without needing to store them.

Is there some similar method available in linux environment that can fetch the command line argument?

Comment: No. ______________

Comment: You could probably write such a function if you really want it, using the contents of `/proc/self/cmdline` as a starting point.

Comment: When  you say `int main` function, I presume you mean C/C++. In which case you can write a simple function to call at startup to save the `argv[]` strings for later retrieval (after all `argv[]` is writable, so content can be changed) Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Comment: BTW: No need to stre the arguments in main, because the args will persist during runtime. You only need a pointer to the args stored somewhere. Additional info also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057961/how-to-access-argv-from-outside-the-main-function

Comment: Unless the arguments are changed.E.g. `*argv[1] = 'c';`

Comment: @TobySpeight Is the file '/proc/self/cmdline' available on all ubuntu distributions. Are there some circumstances when this file is not available? Because all I want is get access to the commandline argument without storing them in my program.

Comment: Please read the commands carefully. You already got a link to the answer how to "store" the data you need. In fact, you only need a single pointer which points to an array of pointers to strings. One line of code! Not more...

Comment: @Klaus, did you miss David's observation that `argv` content can be (and is, by some argument parsing libraries) overwritten during program execution?

Comment: @TobySpeight: If you already use a parsing library, why would you store the args again? I never saw that behavior of damaged args and never had the use case to use a lib and store it for a different and later use. Maybe an XY problem?